# How can I use string interpolation in a parameterized test?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am doing some API testing in C# with NUnit and RestSharp. I would like to parameterize my GET tests so I am not doing a lot of repeated tests. The problem I am running into is that I have an `assignmentGuid` which goes into the request. Currently, I am doing the request like so with string interpolation. `LufasApiService.SendGetRequestWithResponse($"v2/audit?assignmentGuid={_assignmentGuid}&unitNumber=450&auditPeriodId=1500");`

Here is what I have for the parameterized test:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("GetAPIRequests")]
    public void TestGetAPIs(string url, string responseContent) 
    {
        var response = LufasApiService.SendGetRequestWithResponse(url);
        Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        Assert.That(response.ContentType, Is.EqualTo("application/json"));
        Assert.That(response.Content.Contains(responseContent));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string[]> GetAPIRequests()
    {
        yield return new string[] { $"v2/audit?assignmentGuid={_assignmentGuid}&unitNumber=450&auditPeriodId=1500", "auditInstanceGuid" };
    }
```

The message I am getting is `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'APITests._assignmentGuid'`

I am not sure what is going on with this and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: The message is pretty clear, `GetAPIRequests()` is static, and `_assignmendGuit` is not (I assume it's a field in the test class or something)

Comment: Thank you, I made the `_assignmentGuid` static and that fixed the issue.

Comment: The error message you're encountering is related to the usage of a non-static field "_assignmentGuid" in a static method "GetAPIRequests()". In C#, you cannot reference instance members (non-static fields, properties, or methods) from a static context directly.

Comment: Prefer `[TestCaseSource(nameof(GetAPIRequests))]` over `[TestCaseSource("GetAPIRequests")]`.

Comment: Another option you can pass string as `"v2/audit?assignmentGuid={0}&unitNumber=450&auditPeriodId=1500"` (without leading $) and then format it directly in the test using `string.Format(url, _assignmentGuid)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Lennart and @AztecCodes for the suggestions. I made the `_assignmentGuid` static and the test worked splendidly.